# IOS equivalent of Android selector

Tags: ios, swift3, background-image

I am trying to find the IOS (Swift 3) substitute or alternative or equivalent of the **selector** in android programming. Since there is a totally different selector concept in Swift language, it is really hard to find this kind of question anywhere.

A simple android selector example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_disabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_disabled" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

What I want to do is so simple.

- Create a selector-like structure for 3 states (preferably a Gradient color combination).
- Set it to some UILabel or UIImage or UIButton as background.
- And I want the interaction-enabled label or image or button to change background when pressed, enabled and disabled.

If there is not any alternative, **IMHO**, the only way to achieve this very simple structure in IOS will be a huge pain in the neck. You will probably have to catch touch events for labels, images and buttons separately. You will probably have to implement different background changing codes separately. You will probably have to have to use different ways of creating a gradient colored backgrounds for each component.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android selector, but are you looking for this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolstate ?

Answer (score 0):

@Larme I think has the correct answer - you are looking for different control states - .normal, .highlighted, .selected. Just set the different images based on their control state.

Comment: thank you but this is the first step. How can you set gradient background images for different states for different controls? Can you show an example?